# Run the app inside dialog view

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme, android-dialog

I have one activity which is a dialog in my app.

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:name="com.example.myapp.AuthActivity" />
```

and it contains a button `run your app inside this dialog view itself`

On clicking this button, App should run or open under this dialog.

Is this possible? or its a worst question?

Could anyone help me out in this?

Comment: So you want to run other apps inside your floating view?

Answer (score 0):

I think so Its not possible to run other app inside a dialog. Android will not allow to run or display other app inside any dialog, views etc. Its not Web Development where you show other websites in a iframe, frame etc.

I think so the best solution for this is to separately launch other app by pressing button.